# VS 2019 Configuration Manager shows blank configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2019, csproj

Below is the Xamarin Forms solution but I have witnessed the same in WPF solution too. App.iOS project has blank configurations.
What's worse, you are not able to Add New ones by scrolling down and pressing `<New...>` - It does nothing. If you try to `<Edit...>` and remove/rename the blank ones, you get an error "The operation could not be completed".

I would like to remove blank rows, and be able to add new configurations using the `<New...>` button.

What I've tried:

- Cleaning and rebuilding project
- Rebooting Visual studio and PC
- Tempering with App.iOS.csproj file, no blank data in there, nothing looked wrong to me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have to start at the .sln file, it lists the projects.  If it is corrupted beyond hope then simply create a new solution and add the existing projects back.

Comment: @HansPassant Above is from .sln file.

Comment: Hmm, no, it is a screenshot.  Looking at App.iOS.csproj  made no sense, that's not where the problem is located.

Comment: @HansPassant the screenshot is of "Solution Configuration Manager", the "Active solution configuration:" drop-down shows all configurations correctly, and nothing is corrupted there. Only the child project (App.iOS) is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe this will help you.  I had the same issue on my solution today and found your post.

I tried messing around with the sln file manually without luck.

My solution:
Since my project was x86 only I ended up clicking the edit in the Active solutions platform: dropdown.

[image: Configuration Manager]

I removed the items x64 and Any CPU.  Then I went to each project and checked if it still had those two entries.  Some did and I removed them.  To my surprise when I then clicked the dropdown for one of the projects that had blank entries they were gone and so was the ones for the second project that had the blank entries too.  Hopefully this will work for you.